# How to set a bot's status per server / guild

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am trying to set my discord bot's status differently depending on the discord server.

I know how to set the status using `client.user.setActivity`

However I want to be able to set a different status for each discord server.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sadly not possible and a limitation of the Discord API itself.